# Implementing state design pattern using C++/CLI or C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, c++-cli

I am trying to implement the state design pattern using C++/CLI. This pattern requires that the State class be a friend of the Context. But C++/CLI does not allow a friend class. I understand that this is also the case with C#. Has anyone implemented the state pattern with C++/CLI or C#? I would like to know how you got around the absence of friend class.

Comment: C# has the `internal` visibility making something accessible only to code from the same assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done using Association (or what all the cool kids are calling Dependency Injection).  Inject the state into the context. See the implementation on [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, I implemented a version similar to what was suggested in DoFactory.

Comment: It still doesn't give the same flexibility as using a friend class as the state object doesn't have private access to the context

Answer (score 0):

Having the State class be a friend of the Context class is not a *requirement* for implementing the State pattern. Wikipedia has an [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Example) without using the friend modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep state in a subclass, then replace sub class object with a different inheriting type when state changes.

```
class YourClass
{
  private MyEnum _myStateEnum; // Wrap this with a public property
  private MyInnerClass _myStateLogic; // Change this with appropriate type when above changes

  public void AnExampleMethod()
  {
      _myStateLogic.AnExampleMethod();
  }

  internal abstract class MyInnerClass
  {
      public virtual abstract void AnExampleMethod();
  }

  internal class MyOtherInnerClass1: MyInnerClass
  {
      public override void AnExampleMethod() { }
  }

  internal class MyOtherInnerClass2: MyInnerClass
  {
      public override void AnExampleMethod() { }
  }
}
```